# htaccess - convert URI to redirect as parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this line in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^potato/?$ /potato.php
```

So when I type:

```
example.com/potato/
```

I will get:

```
example.com/potato.php
```

however, for a specific reason, I need to change the URL from:

```
example.com/potato/
```

to

```
example.com/
```

Because There is some process in `potato.php` require URL to be like that.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You mean `RewriteRule ^potato/?$ /`...?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you insist on using a rewrite for that, you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /potato.php
```

However, it would be better in my opinion to use the [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) directive of Apache instead, so add this to your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex potato.php index.php index.html
```